Identify an (possibly) Indian film involving a forest fire and a huge croc
I saw this film in the early 90's but I am estimating that it was probably a bit older (80's or 70's). The setting was oriental, mostly likely Indian. (It was dubbed into my native language.) Things I remember:

A love story between a teenage boy and a teenage girl was an important plot thread.
The film took place in a village or a small town surrounded by a jungle.
There was a scene where someone swung himself using a rope or a vine over a pond that had a huge crocodile. The croc tried to bite the person but missed.
The same croc later devoured some baddie(s).
There was a huge forest fire at the end.

I really loved this film as a child and would really like to see it again. Thank you!

Jungle Book was a 1942 color adaptation of Rudyard Kipling's famous book about Mowgli, a feral child who lives in an Indian jungle. The film was nominated for 4 Oscars. From the IMDb synopsis:

Teenaged Mowgli, who was raised by wolves, appears in a village in India and is adopted by Messua. Mowgli learns human language and some human ways quickly, though keeping jungle ideas. Influential Merchant Buldeo is bigoted against 'beasts' including Mowgli; not so Buldeo's pretty daughter, whom Mowgli takes on a jungle tour where they find a treasure, setting the evil of human greed in motion. 

Mowgli befriends a girl named Mahala and the film features killer crocs and a jungle fire near the end. Here's the trailer:



